# getRange.getValue returning wrong date from Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, getvalue

var `sheetdate = activeSheet.getRange(x,  y).getValue()` I was using this line to read a date from google sheets. Date in sheets is 2021-02-01. But sheetdate is returning value *Sun Jan 31 13:30:00 GMT-05:00 2021*. Actual output should be Mon Feb 1 17:35:00 GMT 05:30

Comment: It seem a timezone problem. Have you tried to convert the value (returned as GMT timezone) to your timezone)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the timezone as Sourcerer mentioned.

There are many possible answers to this one but I prefer this one, formatting the date using `Utilities` as you can control your output:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  date = sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue()
  Logger.log(date);
  Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone());
  Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(date, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"));
}
```

For the formatting, the one I used above `"E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"` is trying to emulate the default date output. See the reference below and feel free to modify based on what you need to output for the date

**Referenece:**

- [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone)